# Flutter NFC Manager issue on ios

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, nfc

I am using Flutter nfc_manager just for writing URLs on NFC Tags in android it's working perfectly. But on IOS it's not written anything on a tag or not showing any error also.

On their documentation for IOS setup, they are saying to do this

```
Add Near Field Communication Tag Reader Session Formats Entitlements to your entitlements.

Add NFCReaderUsageDescription to your Info.plist.

Add com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes and com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers to your Info.plist as needed.
```

I have done the first and second steps only. Seems like the third step is only for reading tags which I don't want to use in my app. I need to add this third step Also how to add this I am using the NFC tag of Protocol: ISO14443A

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have same issue in starting when i implement this first time so yes you need to add these 2 things in info.plist like this

```
    <key>NFCReaderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow access to Create Sticker</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes</key>
     <array>
       <string>8005</string>
       <string>8008</string>
       <string>0003</string>
       <string>fe00</string>
       <string>90b7</string>
       <string>927a</string>
       <string>86a7</string>
     </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>A0000002471001</string>
        <string>A000000003101001</string>
        <string>A000000003101002</string>
        <string>A0000000041010</string>
        <string>A0000000042010</string>
        <string>A0000000044010</string>
        <string>44464D46412E44466172653234313031</string>
        <string>D2760000850100</string>
        <string>D2760000850101</string>
        <string>00000000000000</string>
    </array>
```

In this NFC tag of Protocol: ISO14443A will also work because i have also same tags and working fine.

Edit: Also after save run pod install also.

Comment: Thanks after doing this finally got a popup for Nfc writing on tag and its also working thanks again

Comment: I have an NFC chip with the same protocol. Can I use the same codes or do I have to use different ones?